# How to change creation time of objects during run time if the repository is shared repository?

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

I am trying launch browser using UFT without closing existing instances of browsers. I know that we can use SetTOProperty method to change creation time during runtime.but this is not working for shared repositories as they are associated to the action in read-only mode. If there is no solution for this, is there any way to copy the objects in the shared repository into local repository?
Thanks.